# Как реализовать проверку файлов при загрузке по хешу?

Tags: php, backend

Всем привет! Вопрос по PHP.

При загрузке файлов на сервер надо реализовать их проверку по хешу, чтобы пользователи не могли загружать повторно одни и те же файлы, пусть и с разными названиями. Вопрос - как это сделать? Я новичок, не могу разобраться.

Можно ли как-то обойти все файлы, которые уже лежат на сервере, и проверить их хеш? Может быть, они автоматически помещаются в какой-то массив и хранятся там?

Comment: А что есть "один и тот же файл"?

Comment: это файлы одинаковым хешем. задача в том, чтобы они не плодились на сервере и не перезаписывались

Comment: нет, ты не понял. что есть один  и тот же файл с точки зрения самого файла? то что имя совпадает - это не значит что файл один и тот же.

Comment: а чтобы файлы не перезаписывались достаточно метку времени вписывать или  просто номера присваивать по порядку

Comment: Можно обойти все файлы, которые уже лежат на сервере, и посчитать их хеш, сложить в маасив или бд, и проверять